# Maven Android build error

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

My Maven based project is executing the following command resulting in the error that follows:

Command

```
/bin/sh -c cd /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger && /Users/conor/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/conor/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/target/filtered-manifest/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/src/main/res -S /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_22.0.0/res -m -J /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/target/generated-sources/r --output-text-symbols /Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/target --auto-add-overlay
```

Error

```
/Users/conor/Repositories/Dev/MyPosLogger/samples/HelloMyPosLogger/target/unpacked-libs/android.support_compatibility-v7-appcompat_apklib_22.0.0/res/values-v21/styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
```

Why is this and how do I fix it please?

I am using Android Maven Plugin v3.8.2

Comment: Why not use `Gradle` and add your dependencies to a `build.gradle`?

Comment: Because i've just joined and everything already uses Maven.

Comment: You should really upgrade to use a  newer release of the Android Maven Plugin... 3.8.2 is VERY old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this error before and i solved it by the followin

1. Open Android sdk and make sure latest version of support library is installed or not. If not then install it also check compile pi version for your project is latest or not i.e. 21.

2.After installing just mvn clean install.

This will solve the issue.